# Python: Code is not picking up all string values in list

Tags: python, string, list, directory, subdirectory

I created the following code to create a number of folders

```
import os

Country = {"Albania - AL",
"Armenia - AM",
"Austria - AT",
"Bahrain - BH",
"Belarus - BY",
"Belgium - BE",
"Bulgaria - BG",
"Canary Islands - KY",
"Croatia - HR",
"Cyprus - CY",
"Czech Republic - CZ",
"Denmark - DK",
"Estonia - EE",
"Finland - FI",
"France - FR",
"Germany - DE",
"Greece - GR",
"Hungary - HU",
"Iceland - IS",
"Ireland - IE",
"Israel - IL",
"Italy - IT",
"Latvia - LV",
"Lithuania - LT",
"Luxembourg - LU",
"Malta - MT",
"Morocco - MA",
"Netherlands - NL",
"Norway - NO",
"Poland - PL",
"Portugal - PT",
"Romania - RO",
"Russian Federation - RU",
"Saudi Arabia - SA",
"Serbia - RS",
"Slovakia - SK",
"Slovenia - SI",
"South Africa - ZA",
"Spain - ES",
"Sweden - SW",
"Switzerland - CH",
"Turkey - TR",
"United Arab Emirates - AE",
"United Kingdom Of Great Britain And Northern Ireland - UK",
}

for x in Country:
    path = ("C:/Users/thrnma/Documents/VAT Reporting/" + x)

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

When I run the program, it only generates one folder for Saudi Arabia. I tried running it multiple times, but it will not generate any new folders. I assume I need to do something like loop it through, but I am not sure how to do it (still a novice at Python).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to create the directories in the loop. As it is, you are simply creating one directory, whose name is determined by the last name assigned to `path` in the preceding loop. (Saudi Arabia just happens to be the last element in the *set*, not list, over which you are iterating.)

Comment: The call to `os.mkdir()` is not indented underneath the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put the "creating directory" part in your loop.
This should work, try to understand the difference:

```
import os

Country = {"Albania - AL",
"Armenia - AM",
"Austria - AT",
"Bahrain - BH",
"Belarus - BY",
"Belgium - BE",
"Bulgaria - BG",
"Canary Islands - KY",
"Croatia - HR",
"Cyprus - CY",
"Czech Republic - CZ",
"Denmark - DK",
"Estonia - EE",
"Finland - FI",
"France - FR",
"Germany - DE",
"Greece - GR",
"Hungary - HU",
"Iceland - IS",
"Ireland - IE",
"Israel - IL",
"Italy - IT",
"Latvia - LV",
"Lithuania - LT",
"Luxembourg - LU",
"Malta - MT",
"Morocco - MA",
"Netherlands - NL",
"Norway - NO",
"Poland - PL",
"Portugal - PT",
"Romania - RO",
"Russian Federation - RU",
"Saudi Arabia - SA",
"Serbia - RS",
"Slovakia - SK",
"Slovenia - SI",
"South Africa - ZA",
"Spain - ES",
"Sweden - SW",
"Switzerland - CH",
"Turkey - TR",
"United Arab Emirates - AE",
"United Kingdom Of Great Britain And Northern Ireland - UK",
}

for x in Country:
    path = ("C:/Users/thrnma/Documents/VAT Reporting/" + x)

    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
    else:
        print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Comment: Ah, it was the indent. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just fix the indentation of your try block. That's it.

It should be something like this:

```
for x in Country:
    path = ("C:/Users/thrnma/Documents/VAT Reporting/" + x)

    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
    else:
        print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `os.mkdir(path)` part inside for loop.

```py
for x in Country:
    path = ("C:/Users/thrnma/Documents/VAT Reporting/" + x)

    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
    else:
        print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```